# I need to find out odd and even occurences of double quotes

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

I need to find out odd and even occurrences of double quotes in a text file line by line in notepad++ and replace odd occurrence with “ and even with ”.

```
arch\" target=\"_blank\"\u003ELearn
more\u003C/a\u003E","hen":true,"h1":"en-IN","htt":"List
ening for \"Ok Google\"","im":"Click
\u003Cb\u003EAllow\u003C/b\u003E to start voice
search","iw":"Waiting...","lm":"Listening...","lu":"%1$
s voice search not available","ne":"No Internet
connection","nt":"Didn't get that. \u003Cspan\u003ETry
```

Comment: replace occurrence with the html code of double quotes. Above they have changed in opening and closing double quotes.

Comment: Can't you just replace all occurences of `":"` and `","` with the appropriate quotes?

Comment: no, I want output to be like..arch\&ldquo; target=\&rdquo;_blank\&ldquo;\u003ELearn
                                                                                                     more\u003C/a\u003E&ldquo;,&rdquo;hen&ldquo;:true,&rdquo;h1&ldquo;:&rdquo;en-IN&ldquo;,&rdquo;htt&ldquo;:&rdquo;List

Comment: Please provide expected result for the sample input, in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this in two passes:

1. Replace the pairs of double quotes that belong together:

   **Find what:** `"(.*?)"`
   **Replace with:** `“$1”`

   Choose **Regular expression**.
   Do not check the **`.` matches newline** checkbox
2. Replace any dangling quotes that remain:

   **Find what:** `"`
   **Replace with:** `“`